# MongoDB Ignoring duplicate documents using unique key in aggregate

Tags: mongodb, optimization, duplicates, aggregate, grouping

Documents looks like this.

```
{
   "sId": "s1",
   "language": "hindi",
   "service": "editing",
   "count": 5,
},
{
   "sId": "s2",
   "language": "hindi",
   "service": "editing",
   "count": 6,
},
{
   "sId": "s2",
   "language": "hindi",
   "service": "reading",
   "count": 6,
},
{
   "sId": "s3",
   "language": "english",
   "service": "reading",
   "count": 10,
}
```

I want the result should be like this

```
{
  "language":"hindi",
  "count": 11
},
{
  "language":"english",
  "count": 10
}
```

I tried with the aggregate query like this

```
{
  "$group": {
            "_id": {
               "lang": "$language",
               "sId": "$sId"
            },
            "count": {"$sum": "$count"}
        }
}
```

In `sId: s2` it should ignore the second object.

Can anyone please give me a hint how I can achieve the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) to get the first element of each group. You can then use `$group` again to sum by `language`.

```
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "language": "$language",
      "sId": "$sId"
    },
    "count": {
      "$first": {
        "$sum": "$count"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/3_RjSt1wtRS

Comment: Is there any way, where we can avoid `allowDiskUse: true` in the option, As there are million of documents in the collection.

Comment: You can try to improve the query by using [`$sort and $group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#optimization-to-return-the-first-document-of-each-group) or by $matching on only a subset of documents. If it's still too slow and you need to run the query often without caching, I would suggest to rework this part of your application to keep track of this information in some other way.